# how to mock the class cast ServletRequest to HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

here is my code ,

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
}
```

request is use to be null. how to mock this lines ?

Comment: ehm, what do you mean 'mock'? mocking instances is part of testing code, not of running code.
you need to pass actual instantiated objects.

Comment: what mocking framework you using? I guess, either you create a real or fake instance in test code and pass while calling `doFilter` method?

Comment: @SabirKhan ya have to pass real instance how i will pass can u send me link or any proper example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create mocks of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`, like following:

```
@Test
public void testDoFilter() throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    FilterChain filterChain = mock(FilterChain.class);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);

    verify(request).getSession(false);
    // other assertions
}
```